# JavaFX - Background insets for custom shapes

Tags: css, javafx-8

How is the `-fx-background-insets` value evaluated if the node's shape is not rectangle, i.e. there are no -meaningful- top-right-bottom-left sides? (The question also arises for `-fx-border-width` etc.)

What I am trying to achieve is to have a `Pane` having triangle shape with different border widths on each side.

```
.triangle-pane {
    -fx-background-color: outer-color, inner-color;
    -fx-shape:  "M 0 4 L 10 1 L 10 7 z";
    -fx-background-insets: 0, ?; // what to write here?
}
```

If I write a single value, it works as expected. If I write more, it behaves weird. I could not figure it out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I believe the background insets are applied to the local bounds, which are just going to be the rectangular region bounding the pane. (This is a bit of a guess, though; I don't have time to check right now.)

Comment: @James_D your guess is definitely wrong since `-fx-background-insets: 0, 2;` results in a proper border-like view around the triangle.

Comment: That's interesting. I'll try and find time to experiment.